# Инстаграм заблокировал аккаунт для приложения

Tags: python, instagram

Недавно установил [instaloader](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/) на питоне с github`а, удобно скачивающий данные с Инстаграма. И пока тестировал некоторые команды, заходя в аккаунт без сессии (каждый раз вводя логин/пароль) — мой аккаунт для приложения заблокировали. В браузере показывается сообщение о необычной попытке входа — https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVlHA.png — но когда я указываю, что это был я — instaloader всё равно не отрабатывает. Через приложение не удаётся войти, даже когда копирую ссылку со скриншота и открываю в браузере, вводя код безопасности — https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jpBu.png. Также блокировал свой аккаунт на 15 часов, но после разблокировки всё равно через instaloader не заходит. Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что надо было обождать — не пользоваться Инстаграмом около 20 часов.